# What is the name of this component with three vertical periods in Google Gmail?

Tags: gmail

What is the name of this component with three vertical periods in Google Gmail?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called a "kebab" (*more options*) menu. As opposed to a "hamburger" *main menu* that consists of three horizontal lines stacked vertically.

From [@MattObee's answer on the User Experience stack](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/115469/3753):

> - The 'kebab' (three vertical dots), which originated in Google's Material Design languge, is designed to open a smaller inline menu from a button or other control.